# using AS3's computeSpectrum() call on arbitrary data?

Tags: actionscript-3, signal-processing, fft

i have some arbitrary signal data which i'd like to get a frequency analysis of. it's not audio data. is there a way to coerce AS3's computeSpectrum() call into doing this work for me ?

tia!

orion

Comment: computeSpectrum() looks like it's a method of the Sound class, so I would guess no. However, perhaps you can save your signal data as a bytearray and cast that as audio? The only issue I see is the actual computation - I don't know if computeSpectrum() works on individual bytes, our groups of four bytes, or something specified by the audio clip, or what.

Comment: thanks for the reply. unfortunately the bytearray passed to computeSpectrum() is the output from the function, not input. afaict it analyzes whatever sound happens to be currently playing.

Comment: @orion elenzil Correct. You could cast your signaldata ByteArray as audio, play it, and run computeSpectrum on it - that was my original idea, but again, I don't know if it'll get you what you want. Hotpaw is probably correct about this....although, maybe it's possible to put an event handler on the sound so that it calls a function when it plays? That seems logical, but I have no experience with sound in AS3 yet. (I'm getting there.)

Comment: Nevermind. I just read the Adobe Livedocs and there's no "start" event - only complete. Sorry about that, definitely shouldn't have made that assumption. :(

Comment: i'll massage it into whatever format is called for, but it could easily be an array of Numbers where each element represents a sample.

Comment: thanks again. i ended up just doing crude signal analysis myself to get what i wanted. i think to get a proper frequency histogram there must be FFT packages out there.

Comment: computeSpectrum is just a function that takes a snapshot of the audio currently playing in the application. It returns a byte array of values for both right and left channels that is all. this is not what you need. If you have an array already then your work is half done. Assuming you are trying to make a visual of the data then all you need you just need to loop through that array and display the data how you want.

Comment: thanks asman. i'm not after just a display of data, i'm looking to get a frequency spectrum analysis of a non-audio signal.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand you. Can you elaborate on frequency spectrum analysis? If you have the byteArray already then you just have to massage it to how you want. If you want to display the frequency data in a graphical way like an audio analyzer then you have to create an audio file(mp3) out of it and use computeSpectrum in a loop as the mp3 plays to get current values at that time instance. Its actually all not that hard just sounds it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computeSpectrum function seems to take a sample of the currently playing audio on which to perform the FFT.  So you would have to convert your non-audio data into a sound file of some type and play it.  Since there appears to be no way to synchronize play and capture, you would have to loop your data many times in the sound file so it plays for long enough, and hope to get lucky to capture it using a computeSpectrum call.  Very doubtful that this would work and give you meaningful results.